# How to search for pip package containing a module

Tags: python, pip

If you inherited some python code that has `include`'s but you don't know what packages were previously installed in order to satisfy those `include`'s, how can you search for pip packages that contain that module?

In this case, I'm trying to find what pip package(s) to install, in order to satisfy:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
```

By installing `Django`, I was able to satisfy `smart_str` but I still don't have `smart_unicode`.

`pip search` doesn't help, because it just searches for packages whose names match your search. It doesn't tell you which packages contain some particular module or other named object, like `smart_unicode`. There are about a million packages with some variation of `django` in their name.

After figuring out the answer once, I will be writing it into a `requirements.txt` file to prevent this problem in the future with this particular python file.

How can you search for what pip package contains a module?

Comment: I don't know if that exists but you can use google which is highly effective at this, which yields that `smart_unicode` has been replaced by `smart_text` as of Django 2 to align with the initiative of no longer supporting Python 2 in the near future

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using Python 3 and Django 2. Likely what has happened the code you inherited from was written for a version of Django that supported Python 2 as well (likely some version 1.XX) and they failed to provide right django version as a requirement. So you will have to explicitly specify a specific version of django 1.xx while doing a `pip install` so something like `pip install django=1.11` would help.

Here's a quick snippet from a `django 1.11` code that I had handy

```
if six.PY3:
    smart_str = smart_text
    force_str = force_text
else:
    smart_str = smart_bytes
    force_str = force_bytes
    # backwards compatibility for Python 2
    smart_unicode = smart_text
    force_unicode = force_text
```

So replacing all occurrences of `smart_unicode` in your code with `smart_text` would make it work and make it slightly future proof (at-least that part).

For the longer term, think of moving to Python 3 and supported Django version.

Answer (score 0):

This function exists in [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/python3/), but you'll have to either use Python 2 or port over your application to modern Python and modern Django.